# What use is Java 6 interface MultivaluedMap?

Tags: java, data-structures, jax-rs, java-6

What use is Java 6 interface [MultivaluedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html)?

Comment: He's asking for scenarios where such a feature is used.

Comment: I could see it is rarely used, I am interested in use cases ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The interface does not belong to "Java", meaning that the interface is not a part of the core libraries. It is a part of the `javax.ws.rs` hierarchy which is part of the [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) specification. It is used by frameworks implementing the specification such as [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/). It is used whenever maps should refer to not only a single value but to any number of values. An example for the use would be for example the storage of a request header where you one might want to add several values per key. Or even no keys in some cases where it is easier to handle an empty list compared to a `null` value.

Take this HTTP-header for example:

> Accept-Encoding: compress;q=0.5, gzip;q=1.0

You would model this by

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = ...
map.add("Accept-Encoding", "compress;q=0.5");
map.add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip;q=1.0");
```

internally in Jersey. This type of multiple value storage is a common problem in Java that is addressed by other implementors of maps such as [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

This is basically what the javadoc says:

> A map of key-values pairs. Each key can have zero or more values.

Comment: Here is an example on how to initialize it:
`MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = new MultivaluedMapImpl();`

Answer (score 1):

Its a map of key-values pairs. Each key can have zero or multiple values

```
public interface MultivaluedMap<K,V> extends java.util.Map<K,java.util.List<V>>
```

Comment: Op asked for the uses not the definition

Answer (score 0):

A good use of a MultivaluedMap is with UriInfo. If you are writing a REST endpoint that takes in several QueryParams, you can use UriInfo to get all of the params and extract them using the getQuery() call. For example:

```
public void get(@Context UriInfo ui) {
  MultivaluedMap params = ui.getRequestUri().getQuery();
  // now do what you want with your params
}
```

The MultivaluedMap is helpful because you could have parameters with multiple values. For example if it was a customer database and you wanted to get several customers, your map would have the key of "customerID" and several values linked to it.

Comment: Minor comment - think the call should be getQueryParameters().

Answer (score 0):

**MultiValuedMap** is a part of `javax.ws.rs.core` package, not Core Java. It is mainly used for storing Headers values in requests

```
private MediaType getMediaType(Class entityClass, Type entityType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers) {
     final Object mediaTypeHeader = headers.getFirst("Content-Type");
         ....
}
```

Also, it is quite useful with `UriInfo`

```
private String getJsonpFunctionName(){
    UriInfo uriInfo = getUriInfo();
    if (uriInfo == null) {
        return null;
    }

    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
    if (queryParameters == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return queryParameters.getFirst("jsonp");
}
```